# Launching Intent.ACTION_VIEW intent not working on saved image file

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-intent

First of all let me say that this questions is slightly connected to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951616/launch-intent-viewer-to-display-image-from-url) by me. Actually it was created because of that.

I have the following code to write a bitmap downloaded from the net to a file in the sd card:

```
// Get image from url
URL u = new URL(url);
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(u.toURI());
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
Bitmap bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
instream.close();

// Write image to a file in sd card
File posterFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/Android/data/com.myapp/files/image.jpg");
posterFile.createNewFile();
BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(posterFile));
Bitmap mutable = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmImg,bmImg.getWidth(),bmImg.getHeight(),true);
mutable.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
out.flush();
out.close();

// Launch default viewer for the file
Intent intent = new Intent();                   
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(posterFile.getAbsolutePath()),"image/*");
((Activity) getContext()).startActivity(intent);
```

A few notes. I am creating the "mutable" bitmap after seeing someone using it and it seems to work better than without it. And i am using the parse method on the Uri class and not the fromFile because in my code i am calling these in different places and when i am creating the intent i have a string path instead of a file.

Now for my problem. The file gets created. The intent launches a dialog asking me to select a viewer. I have 3 viewers installed. The Astro image viewer, the default media gallery (i have a milstone on 2.1 but on the milestone the 2.1 update did not include the 3d gallery so it's the old one) and the 3d gallery from the nexus one (i found the apk in the wild).

Now when i launch the 3 viewers the following happen:

- **Astro image viewer:** The activity
  launches but i see nothing but a
  black screen.
- **Media Gallery:** i get an exception
  dialog shown "The application Media
  Gallery (process
  com.motorola.gallery) has stopped
  unexpectedly. Please try again" with
  a force close option.
- **3D gallery:** Everything works as it
  should.

When i try to simply open the file using the Astro file manager (browse to it and simply click) i get the same option dialog but this time things are different:

- **Astro image viewer:** Everything works
  as it should.
- **Media Gallery:** Everything works as it
  should.
- **3D gallery:** The activity launches but
  i see nothing but a black screen.

As you can see everything is a complete mess. I have no idea why this happens but it happens like this every single time. It's not a random bug.

Am i missing something when i am creating the intent? Or when i am creating the image file? Any ideas?

**EDIT:** As noted in the comment here is the part of interest in adb logcat. Also i should note that i changed the way i create the image file. Since i want to create a file that reflects an online file i simply download it instead of creating a Bitmap and then creating the file (this was done because at some point i needed the Bitmap but now i do it the other way around). the problems persist thought and are exactly the same :

> I/ActivityManager(18852): Starting
>   activity: Intent {
>   act=android.intent.action.VIEW
>   dat=/sdcard/Android/data/com.myapp/files/image.jpg
>   typ=image/* flg=0x3800000
>   cmp=com.motorola.gallery/.ViewImage }
>
> I/ActivityManager(18852): Start proc
>   com.motorola.gallery:ViewImage for
>   activity
>   com.motorola.gallery/.ViewImage:
>   pid=29187 uid=10017 gids={3003, 1015}
>
> I/dalvikvm(29187): Debugger thread not
>   active, ignoring DDM send
>   (t=0x41504e4d l=38)
>
> I/dalvikvm(29187): Debugger thread not
>   active, ignoring DDM send
>   (t=0x41504e4d l=64)
>
> I/ActivityManager(18852): Process
>   com.handcent.nextsms (pid 29174) has
>   died.
>
> I/ViewImage(29187): In View Image
>   onCreate!
>
> D/AndroidRuntime(29187): Shutting down
>   VM
>
> W/dalvikvm(29187): threadid=3: thread
>   exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x4001b170)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187): Uncaught
>   handler: thread main exiting due to
>   uncaught exception
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.motorola.gallery/com.motorola.gallery.ViewImage}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
>   Method)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
>   Method)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   com.motorola.gallery.ImageManager.allImages(ImageManager.java:5621)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   com.motorola.gallery.ImageManager.getSingleImageListByUri(ImageManager.java:5515)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   com.motorola.gallery.ViewImage.onCreate(ViewImage.java:1801)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
>
> E/AndroidRuntime(29187):  ... 11 more

Comment: What's the `adb logcat` output for the `com.motorola.gallery` crash? Also, `image/*` isn't technically a valid mimetype, you may need to use correct ones like `image/jpeg`.

Comment: also, doesn't the demo apps bundled with the sdk provide a sample that launches the intent as "audio/*"? I thought it would be the same for images...

Comment: Have you tried "image/jpeg" to see what works then?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I used this hack to fix error:

```
...
Uri hacked_uri = Uri.parse("file://" + uri.getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(hacked_uri, "image/*");
...
```

Comment: You my friend are a life saver :)

Comment: NB: I had set data and type in two separate calls which did not work. Setting them in one call as done here solved the problem for me.

Comment: The key for me was to using `image/*` as the type. Samsung's Gallery app worked fine with `image/jpg`, but Motorola's Gallery app didn't (I was receiving `ActivityNotFoundException`).

Comment: Prepending "file://" before the path did the trick! Vlad you're the man!!

Answer (score 4):

I used this code for my app and works fine. I only did a litle change.

I changed This:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(posterFile.getAbsolutePath()),"image/*");
```

For this:

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(posterFile),"image/*");
```

Answer (score 2):

I decided to create my own Activity which simply draws the image on the screen. It is not a perfect solution but it meets my basic standards... It works :)

Answer (score 0):

i use this code

```
 MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(PayamKhosusiActivity.this, new String[] { filez.toString() },
                        null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                                Log.wtf("onScanCompleted", "yes");


                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                                intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                                intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION); //must for reading data from directory

                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
```