# The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type?

Tags: android, android-activity, widget

So im trying to start an activity by pressing a widget. I keep running into the error "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type Photos" any help is much appreciated! My class code is below:

```
package com.natehoch96.widgets.iOS;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Intent;


public class Photos extends AppWidgetProvider {

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
    {startActivity(myIntent); }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement the onUpdate() and onReceive() methods in your AppWidgetProvider class, something like this:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, 
    int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        //Get the views for your widget layout
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), 
            R.layout.my_widget);

        //Create a pending intent for a widget click
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Photos.class);
        intent.setAction("PhotosAction");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = 
            PendintIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_click_view, pendingIntent);

        appWidgetManager.updateAddWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }
}
```

Then write your onReceive() method to receive the pending intent and start the relevant activity:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (intent.getAction().equals("PhotosAction") {
        //Received photos action action, start your target activity
        Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! For some reason though it didnt work on HTC Sense, but I feel like that might just be something with Sense because it worked in my emulator. Also, say I wanted it to launch the Photos app instead, how would I go about figuring out that system defined intent. Thanks for the help

Comment: are you trying to view an image, that is you have a URI and want to launch a viewer, if so take a look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954594/launching-intent-action-view-intent-not-working-on-saved-image-file). I'm not sure you can rely on a 'system defined intent' as different manufacturers may provide their own gallery apps, e.g. HTC, Samsung..

Answer (score 0):

What method have you put this code in? `AppWidgetProvider` does not have a `startActivity()` method. You need a `Context` for that. Several of `AppWidgetProvider`'s callback methods give you access to a `Context` object, but it all really depends on what you intend to do.

I suggest you take a look at the Android developer guide's documentation on AppWidgets [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#Providers).

Comment: Ok I'm extremely new at developing so what exactly is a Context and how would I use it? I tried looking in the documentation but it didnt really help me, any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks