# Need a Good Tutorial on Interactions With Android Home Screen Widget ... if any

Tags: java, android, widget

First of all I'm a total noob (as you might noticed) in Android environment. I'll try to be as short as possible if you'll need any explanation please ask.

The App Widget itself as simple as:
1. I'm trying to create a simple app widget with a button.
2. When you click on the button "Hello World" Toast message pops out.

I've succeeded in making all the GUI. I declared all the necessary strings in AndroidManifest.xml, I've layuout'ed the widget itself - it's fully working and have a nice visuals, all the buttons are clickable and even have onFocus and onPressed states declared.

What I've failed in is I just can't make this buttons to call for some action or function or class or whatever. I've read a lot through [This tutorial on dev.Android website](http://goo.gl/j2vn) (it sucks hard btw), I've also read other tutorials I've googled out (generaly they just copypasting the dev.Android's tuts), nothing works, nothing at all explains how it works.

Please help me to find the tutorial which really helps to get widgets working.

You rule anyway! Thank you!

Comment: check this. I learned a lot from here http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developers-tutorial-for.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not called widgets, you should refer them as 'app widgets' or 'home screen widgets'.

I think this link will be helpful to you - http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html#simplewidget

Update: Opening browser on the button click in app widget

```
Intent openBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/"));                       

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, openBrowser , 0);

remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.mybutton, pendingIntent);
```

I assume, your Button *id* in *xml* is *mybutton* and you have already initialized remoteViews.

Comment: Thanx! Corrected! ... yes I've found this tutorial on Google, but I did evrth. like they say and nothing worked. Maybe I should read it from scratch once again.

Comment: If you are able to toast hello world, you will also be able to do this just give it another try. If then you face some problem you can post a question.

Comment: Yes I can do Toasts it's not a problem for me! Making toasts is so much easier than interaction with the external activity )))

Comment: The thing is all this tutorials are about updating the widget on button click and I want just a Toast or Browser window opened or anything except updating the widget ... any thoughts mr.Wizzard? ))

Comment: seems like a good idea but I don't understand where should I put this to make it work ))) ... I guess public onUpdate() is not a good place for this script

Comment: I kinda figured it out with the help of <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/a/7037004/1614492">this awesome reply</a> ... Your tutorial was quite helpful anyway! Merci beaucoup! ;)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reply it was night in India. Glad my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help you with the Toast widget:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html

When you are creating your layout lets say you added a button as so in a layout file we'll called myLayout.xml:

```
<Button    
android:id="@+id/Button"
android:text="@string/Button_Name"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="Method_Name"/>
```

Then in your class you have:

```
//necessary imports
public class myActivity extends Activity
{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
    }

    public void Method_Name(View view)
    {
        //Here you would put what you needed from the toast tutorial 
        //So I'll demonstrate how to make hello world pop up
        Context context=getApplicationContext();
        String message="Hello world!";

        Toast toast=new Toast(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
```

So what's happening here? Well in our class myActivity we set a contentView which loads our layout file to the screen, in this layout file we have a button (there's other stuff but that is auto generated and there's plenty on the internet and layouts are a different topic). This button using the onClick property is stating a method to be called in the class that its inflated inside. Then when you click the button the method METHOD_NAME is called. In that we create a Toast widget, give it a context, the message it displays and how long it will stay on the screen. Then using toast.show() we display the toast notification to the user.

I hope this has made things clearer, if you need any more explanation or assistance just say.

Comment: I can make toasts, my problem is I can't call toasts from the HomeScreen Widget  ... but anyway thank you that a good piece of advice and might help someone to make a good toast! ;)