# How can I show the full size of Image when an image was clicked in GridView?

Tags: java, android, gridview

I saw this example in the internet, What do I need to do is just add a code on how can i show the full size of image once I clicked a picture in the Gridview. Any Idea?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
    gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
      .getExternalStorageDirectory()
      .getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files){
     myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    } 
}
```

I think this is the Adapter class.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Context mContext;
 ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

 public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
  mContext = c; 
 }

 void add(String path){
  itemList.add(path); 
 }

@Override
public int getCount() {
return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ImageView imageView;
     if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
         imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
         imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
         imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
     } else {
         imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
     }

     Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

     imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
     return imageView;
     }

     public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

     Bitmap bm = null;
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
     options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

    return bm;   
    }

    public int calculateInSampleSize(

    BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    if (width > height) {
    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
    } else {
    inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
    }   
    }

    return inSampleSize;    
   }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a click listener to your GridView. From there you have to open a second Activity that shows the full size image.

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String path = mAdapter.getItem(position);
        Intent i = new Intent(AndroidTestActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("path", path);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Or you use the built in functionality of Android:
[Launching Intent.ACTION_VIEW intent not working on saved image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954594/launching-intent-action-view-intent-not-working-on-saved-image-file)

Comment: How to create the second Activity?

Comment: Please use Google for such basic stuff: https://www.google.com/search?q=android+activity . The second result points you to the Android docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html

Comment: How will i get the Intent? Can you add the missing parts? Im new with this.

Comment: Everything is described in the Android documentation (second link in the above comment)

Comment: In my First Activity, ex. the AndroidTestActivity I will put the setOnItemClickListener and then I will create a new class called, for ex, the DetailActivity after what will I put? I already tried that.

Comment: Use the code from the answer above. Set the URL to the image as an extra in the Intent. In your DetailActivity.onCreate() function you can get the URL back with getIntent().getStringExtra("path"). I would suggest you do some reading in the documentation first to learn how Activities work. This is pretty basic stuff.

Comment: Im just getting a black screen.