# View image in android built-in viewer

Tags: android, android-activity, android-imageview

I need to view the image in android default image viewer when i execute the following code it's shows the album list instead Of particular image. please correct me.

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {receiptPath}, new String[] {"image/*"}, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: is recepitPath a folder or file?

Comment: it is file ex. /mnt/sdcard/com.example.folder/receipt.png

Comment: if it is a file, this might be of help  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954594/launching-intent-action-view-intent-not-working-on-saved-image-file/3677598#3677598

Comment: sorry still unable to view the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question see the answer below

```
@Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

after analyse the android Intent source code my learning is, if you set uri in Intent constructor then set type, the data uri automatically set to null, so i can't access the particular image in image viewer.

[Refer the source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.setType%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: There's usually no need to set the type. The type is inferred from the data. I only use `setType` if there is no data (I.e. the type is used only for resolution purposes or to specify a result type).

Comment: @keyboardr but in some case if i try to view a pdf document, if i didn't gave the type i got ActivityNotFound Exception. If i specify the type i can view the document using Office suite app

Comment: Sometimes Android won't be able to infer the mimetype and that's what the setDataAndType() method is for. For images, though, it shouldn't normally have a problem.