# displaying local resource using Intent.ACTION_VIEW fails

Tags: android

I want to display a file that I include in the apk. I can put the thumbnail into a small ImageView and when the user clicks it, I want to show the full size using Gallery (or whatever image viewing app the user has)

Below is the clicklistener :  I want to pull the full size out of the "raw" folder and start and activity.  I am getting a failure

```
private OnClickListener showImage = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.invodo.allshareplay/" + R.raw.dropbox_photo1));
        intent.setType("image/jpeg");
        startActivity(intent);

    }

};
```

--- logcat ----

```
03-13 11:16:33.704: E/AndroidRuntime(10466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-13 11:16:33.704: E/AndroidRuntime(10466): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:     No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW   dat=android.resource://com.invodo.allshareplay/2130968576 }
03-13 11:16:33.704: E/AndroidRuntime(10466):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
```

I've tried a few different variations on getting the Uri path, including using the filename as

```
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("android.resource://com.invodo.allshareplay/raw/dropbox_photo1.jpg"));
```

On the emulator, it tells starts ViewImage but then says the Camera has stopped, unless I take out this line:

```
intent.setType("image/jpeg");
```

and with that commented out it simply fails with no Activity found.

If I put this code on a real device,  it pulls up my images on the phone, but not the image I want to display.  If I take off the SetType call, it simply stops.

regardless of what I maybe doing wrong in getting a proper Uri, 
Any ideas on how to properly display a jpeg image stashed as a raw resource?

Answer (score 0):

This seems a similar problem to the flow that described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954594/launching-intent-action-view-intent-not-working-on-saved-image-file).

The suggested solution is the add **"file://"** as a prefix to the absolute path of the file. so the Intent should be set as followed:

...

```
Uri hacked_uri = Uri.parse("file://" + uri.getPath());
intent.setDataAndType(hacked_uri, "image/*");
...
```

It worked for me...